# ajax通信がうまくいきません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ajax

Ruby on Railsで初めてアプリを作っている初学者です。ajax通信ができず困っています。
jQueryを使って下記の通り作成しました。発火は起きていますが、controllerへ送られていないような感じです。
解決策見つからず、ご教示のほど、お願いいたします。

search.js

```
$(function() {
  var search_list = $("contents.row");
  function appendCompany(company) {
  $(".search-form").on("submit", function() {
    var input = $(".search-input").val();
    console.log(input);
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'get',
      url: '/searches',
      data: { keyword: input },
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(companies) {
     })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("失敗です");
    });
  });
});
```

searches_controller.rb

```
  def search
    @companies = Company.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:keyword]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <div class="search-form">
      <%= form_tag search_user_searches_path(current_user), :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :keyword, "", placeholder: "投稿を検索する", class: "search-input" %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'search_btn' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

rails routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
                    root GET    /                                         searches#index
          user_companies GET    /users/:user_id/companies(.:format)       companies#index
     edit_user_companies GET    /users/:user_id/companies/edit(.:format)  companies#edit
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/companies(.:format)       companies#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/companies(.:format)       companies#update
              user_items GET    /users/:user_id/items(.:format)           items#index
    search_user_searches GET    /users/:user_id/searches/search(.:format) searches#search
           user_searches GET    /users/:user_id/searches(.:format)        searches#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/searches(.:format)        searches#create
         new_user_search GET    /users/:user_id/searches/new(.:format)    searches#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                    user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url: '/searches'`
が route に存在してないですね
`url:  $(this).attr('action')`
にしないといけないのでは？

あと普通 rails で ajax するときは form に remote: true ってつけるだけで勝手に ajax になります
js のビューを書くことで JSON 受取処理も書く必要がなく直接 ajax の結果を JS として実行できるので便利です

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事できました！